# Bad index while coercing array into hash in Perl

Tags: perl

Below is the code

```
my $results = $session->array_of_hash_for_cursor("check_if_receipts_exist", 0, @params);
next if( scalar @{$results} <= 0 );
$logger->info("Retrieved number of records: ".scalar @$results);
foreach my $row( sort { $results->{$b}->{epoch_received_date} cmp $results->{$a}->{epoch_received_date} } keys %{$results} )
      {
       //logic
      }
```

'check_if_receipts_exists' is a SQL query which returns some results. Which I try to execute this, I am getting the following error,
Bad index while coercing array into hash

I am new to Perl. Can someone please point out the mistake I am making?

Comment: Where is `$session` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `$results` a hash reference or an array reference?

In some places you are using it like an array reference:

```
scalar @{$results}
```

and in other places you are using it like a hash reference:

```
$results->{$b}->{...}
keys %{$results}
```

It can't be both (at least not without some heavy [`overload`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload) magic).

If I can infer from the name of the function that sets `$results`, it should be a reference to a list of hash references, then a few tweaks will set it right:

1. Using `@{$results}` is correct; this expression is "an array of hash references"
2. The last argument to `sort` should be a list, but the correct list to pass is `@{$results}`, not `keys %{$results}`.
3. Then the parameters `$a` and `$b` inside the `sort` function will be members of `@{$results}`, that is, they will be hash references. So the comparison to make is

> `$a->{epoch_received_date} cmp $b->{epoch_retrieve_data}`
>   
>   and not

```
    $results->{$a}->{...} cmp $results->{$b}->{...}
```

All together:

```
my $results = $session->array_of_hash_for_cursor(
   "check_if_receipts_exist", 0, @params);
next if !@$results;
$logger->info("Retrieved number of records: ".@$results);
for my $row (
    sort {
        $b->{epoch_received_date}
          cmp
        $a->{epoch_received_date}
    } @$results
) {
   # logic
}
```

Comment: After making the above changes, I am getting the following error, Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not array dereference) at ...

Comment: @carkct - Read the suggestions again. I doubt there is any need to use `keys`. I'm guessing you should be using `sort {...} @{$results}`.

Comment: And keep your chin up. This stuff is complicated and confusing, but once you get the hang of it, it is very powerful and expressive.

Comment: I tried using foreach my $row( sort { {$b}->{epoch_received_date} cmp {$a}->{epoch_received_date} } @{$results} ) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @ikegami - I think there is an error in summary code (`next if @$results` seems reverse logic to OP's code)